# Mysql query optimization and decrease count of query

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, view, query-optimization

I'm using PHP & MYSQL database, I want to get the details above the particular account. I'm using  4 queries to get the details for an account "amar". 
My requirement is that I have to use only one query and i have to decrease the execution time and improve query optimization. I think, it would be better if we use views or stored procedures concepts.  I have create a fiddle in sqlfiddle.com.  [This is link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e48f6/2)

**Requirement :**

1. sum of product price assigned to the  account ( amar ) . product must assigned to category either 'category1' or 'category2' .
2. number of product assigned to  the  account ( amar ) . where product must assigned to category either 'category1' or 'category2' .

For above two requirement , I have used this following query.

```
select  SUM(p.price) as sum , count(p.id) as count from account as a left join aproduct as p on a.id = p.account_id and p.category in ('category1','category2') where a.id = '1' group by a.id
```

3. get the total number of product assigned to  the  account ( amar ).

For the above  requirement , I have used this following query.

```
select a.id , a.name,   count(p.id)   from account as a left join aproduct as  p on a.id = p.account_id  where a.id = '1'   group by a.id
```

4. In  the  account ( amar ), get the oldest date of product's added_date + 115 days where product assigned to category either 'category1' or 'category2'

For the above  requirement , I have used this following query.

```
 select a.id , a.name ,   ( select ADDDATE( MIN(p.added_date)  ,  INTERVAL  115 DAY   ) ) as added_date  from account as a left join aproduct as  p on a.id = p.account_id  and  p.category IN ('category1','category2')  where a.id = '1'  group by a.id
```

5. In  the  account ( amar ), get the oldest date of product's available_date where product assigned to category either 'category1' or 'category2'
6. In  the  account ( amar ), get the  second oldest date of product's available_date where product assigned to category either 'category1' or 'category2'
7. In  the  account ( amar ), get the third oldest date of product's available_date where product assigned to category either 'category1' or 'category2'

For above three requirements, I think we can get the records using following query

```
select a.id , a.name , p.available_date as added_date  from account as a left join aproduct as  p on a.id = p.account_id  and  p.category IN ('category1','category2')  where a.id = '1' order by p.available_date asc limit 0,3
```

**My assumption about the final query  which i want :**

```
select sum, count, min(added_date), first_oldest_date, second_oldest_date, third_oldest_date from table or view or stored procedure  where account.id = '1'
```

**MY SQL DATABASE & TABLE DEFINITION.**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `account`
--

INSERT INTO `account` (`id`, `name`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'amar', '2014-10-06'),
(2, 'kumar', '2014-10-14'),
(3, 'ram', '2014-10-13');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `aproduct`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aproduct` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `available_date` date NOT NULL,
  `added_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `aproduct`
--

INSERT INTO `aproduct` (`id`, `account_id`, `name`, `price`, `category`, `available_date`, `added_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'prodcut one', '20', 'category1', '2014-10-02', '2014-10-08 00:00:00'),
(2, 2, 'product two', '30', 'category2', '2014-10-05', '2014-10-03 00:00:00'),
(3, 1, 'product three', '30', 'category1', '2014-10-01', '2014-10-23 00:00:00'),
(4, 3, 'product four', '36', 'category4', '2014-09-03', '2014-10-04 00:00:00'),
(5, 2, 'product five', '54', 'category2', '2014-10-07', '2014-10-14 00:00:00'),
(6, 1, 'product six', '66', 'category6', '2014-10-03', '2014-10-06 00:00:00');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you create a http://sqlfiddle.com with your db and query then someone might help you

Comment: Thanks @Mikpa. i have added my db and query in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: yes the best way is using stored procedure concept, but here is the part I did not get. For some record(last part of sql) it need you to take 3 record while on the other you only will take 1 records

Comment: @Martono halim, Thanks for you reply. For last query,i have used  limit 0,3. so in a single query, i can able to get three datas like first oldest date, second oldest date and third oldest date. Otherwise, i have to use three more queries.  I want a query like select sum, count, min(added_date), first_oldest_date, second_oldest_date, third_oldest_date from table or view or stored procedure .

Comment: I see, then I think the best is just separate it like that, or you create some procedure and stored into one table